# Hosting sitemap files on a subdomain

Tags: sitemap, subdomain, xml-sitemap, xml

I have a website lets say xyz.com for which i have the sitemap index at **xyz.com/sitemap.xml**

Within the **sitemap index** file there are multiple sitemap links which are hosted on a subdomain of xyz.com lets say **sitemap.xyz.com**.

So the structure of sitemap index file  is as follows

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://sitemap.xyz.com/sitemap1.xml
</loc>
</sitemap>

<sitemap>
<loc>
https://sitemap.xyz.com/sitemap2.xml
</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Also i have submitted the sitemap index file in Google search console and google correctly shows the total count of pages from all sitemaps

Is this structure recommended or will there be any issue with this architecture

PS This question is not about cross domain sitemaps

Comment: The possibly duplicate question mentioned above talks about cross domain sitemaps, however i am referring to sitemap hosted on a subdomain of the same domain

Comment: Fair, though I tend to believe that the answer will be exactly the same. There's no reason for me to think it would work on a separate TLD but not on a subdomain.